# Foreigner buying Russian stocks without physically visiting Russia?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, russia

Is it actually possible for a foreigner to invest in Russian stocks without physically visiting Russia?

I assume you need an account in Russian bank, which can be done when you're in Russia, but is it possible to open such account in other way (remotely) or buy stock via other stack exchanges?

My current trading system (Switzerland) allows me to buy for example German or US stocks, but not Russian.

Comment: At the very least, the biggest Russian companies are traded at foreign exchanges, e.g. NYSE. You should be able to buy that stocks without visiting Russia, like any other stocks from those exchanges.

Comment: @Petr but those are not the same stocks, to my understanding, but fully separate emissions? OK it looks I have a lot to learn.

Comment: I don't know if you can indeed call them a separate emissions, but as far as I understand, they are fully equal to those traded in Russia, in terms of price, dividend, voting rights, etc.

Comment: If I remember correctly, in the late 1990s, only Russian citizens and Russian companies could buy Gazprom shares.  Foreigners only had access to [American Depositary Receipts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_depositary_receipt). I don't think Gazprom shares and ADRs traded at the same price.

Comment: @Petr Was that the case of Gazprom shares in 1998?  I don't think so. Gazprom is of strategic importance and giving voting rights to foreigners would be to surrender sovereignty.